# Why does printing affects order when right folding in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, trace, evaluation

I'm sure it has something to do with lazy evaluation, but still, I just can't give myself an explanation of why it acts this way. Why does evaluating the right hand side in `verboseAdd2` reverse the debug traces output?

This is the code:

```
import Debug.Trace

data BinaryTree = Empty | Node Int BinaryTree BinaryTree

instance Show BinaryTree where
  show Empty = "_"
  show (Node x Empty right) = unwords [           show x, show right]
  show (Node x left  right) = unwords [show left, show x, show right]

add :: Int -> BinaryTree -> BinaryTree
add v Empty = Node v Empty Empty
add v a@(Node x left right)
  | v == x = a
  | v <  x = Node x (add v left) right
  | v >  x = Node x left (add v right)

verboseAdd :: Int -> BinaryTree -> BinaryTree
verboseAdd v a = trace ("[1] Adding v=" ++ show v) (add v a)

verboseAdd2 :: Int -> BinaryTree -> BinaryTree
verboseAdd2 v a = trace ("[2] Adding v=" ++ show v ++ " to " ++ show a) (add v a)

verbosePlus :: (Num a, Show a) => a -> a -> a
verbosePlus left right = trace (show left ++ " + " ++ show right)
                               (left + right)

main :: IO()
main = do
  let seq = [1,2,3,4,5]
  in do print $ foldr verbosePlus 0 seq
        putStrLn ""
        print $ foldr verboseAdd Empty seq
        putStrLn ""
        print $ foldr verboseAdd2 Empty seq
```

This is the output:

```
5 + 0
4 + 5
3 + 9
2 + 12
1 + 14
15

[1] Adding v=1
[1] Adding v=2
[1] Adding v=3
[1] Adding v=4
[1] Adding v=5
1 _ 2 _ 3 _ 4 _ 5 _

[2] Adding v=5 to _
[2] Adding v=4 to 5 _
[2] Adding v=3 to 4 _ 5 _
[2] Adding v=2 to 3 _ 4 _ 5 _
[2] Adding v=1 to 2 _ 3 _ 4 _ 5 _
1 _ 2 _ 3 _ 4 _ 5 _
```

Comment: Put your code in the body of the question - it's not terribly long and the question would be much clearer if everything was in there.

Comment: yes it's because first you only had to force `v` to trace but the second one forces `a` too (remember `a` here is the rest of your expression ;) ) - and while it will eval this `a` all the other traces happen ;)

Comment: *note* that the second one is closer to what is happening - you really start with the last one, but as the `foldr` (or better the structure you return) is lazy this all will end up in a big thunk and will only get evaluated when you start doing your final show (of `"1 _ 2 _ 3 _ 4 _ 5 _"`)

Comment: @Carsten Sorry, I accidentally overwrote your edit - we edited both at the exact same timestamp. Feel free to roll back to your version; I've posted at Meta regarding this, see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309441/simultaneous-editing-exact-same-timestamp-no-warning-when-overwriting-other

Comment: @FrankSchmitt no problem ... it does not really matter where the pasted code is ;)

Comment: @Carsten nailed it. After all, you can't really expect the message "[2] Adding v=1 to 2 _ 3 _ 4 _ 5 _" to be printed before the tree "2 _ 3 _ 4 _ 5 _" is evaluated. So, "2 _ 3 _ 4 _ 5 _" will be evaluated first, but this triggers its own trace. Recursively, we have backward traces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's expand the `foldr` in

```
foldr verboseAdd2 Empty [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

using its definition (abbreviating `verboseAdd2` as `va`):

```
1 `va` (2 `va` (3 `va` (4 `va` (5 `va` Empty))))
```

or, in this case, maybe it's simpler if we use prefix notation:

```
va 1 $ va 2 $ va 3 $ va 4 $ va 5 Empty
```

By the definition of `va`, this reduces to

```
let y1 = va 2 $ va 3 $ va 4 $ va 5 Empty
in trace ("Adding v=1 to " ++ show y1) (add 1 y1)
```

By unrolling more occurrences of `va`, we get

```
let y4 = trace ("Adding v=5 to " ++ show Empty) (add 5 Empty) in
let y3 = trace ("Adding v=4 to " ++ show y4) (add 4 y4) in
let y2 = trace ("Adding v=3 to " ++ show y3) (add 3 y3) in
let y1 = trace ("Adding v=2 to " ++ show y2) (add 2 y2) in
trace ("Adding v=1 to " ++ show y1) (add 1 y1)
```

Hopefully you can see from this that to `show y1` in the outmost `trace`, we first need to evaluate `y1`, which causes `trace ("Adding v=2 to " ++ show y2")` to fire, which forces `y3`, and so on, until we get to `y4`. The `trace` in `y4` doesn't need to force anything else, so it can finally print its message, then go on to evaluate `add 5 Empty`, which is then used by the `trace` in the definition of `y3`, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

There's a lot of comments here, but nobody seems to have written an *answer*...

The answer is of course the `show` function. When you say `x = add 5 myTree`, all you are in fact doing is setting `x` to be an unevaluated expression. `y = add 7 x` sets `y` to be yet another unevaluated expression, and so on. But when you try to `show y`... well, `y` depends on `x`, so first we must evaluate `x`. And *that* is why `trace` prints things out in the order that it does.